# Inline audio from SoundCite is working in JSFiddle but not when loaded locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, inline

Here is my code for my website. It is for a school final. I am trying to use [SoundCiteJS](http://soundcite.knightlab.com) to embed inline audio clips into my article that I wrote. The audio is hosted on SoundCloud and I used the SoundCiteJS website to create embed codes for each audio clip I want (removed from the code below because it is identifying).

The inline audio is embedded perfectly and plays wonderfully when using JSfiddle. However, it doesn't load at all when I open up the HTML file locally. Unfortunately, my professors are going to be grading the assignment by opening all the files locally on their computers.

Any idea what's going on or how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Funding for STEM Education</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.xxxxx.xxxx.edu/xxx/bootcamp/style.css">
<link href='//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/soundcite/latest/css/player.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.knightlab.com/libs/soundcite/latest/js/soundcite.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.xxxx.xxx/xxx/bootcamp/masthead.jpg" alt="Masthead" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 bc-story">
            <h1>No Money, More Problems:<br>How a lack of funding hurts STEM education</h1>
            <h3 class="bc-credit"><a href="aboutme.html">By xxxx</a> | Dec. 4, 2015</h3>
            <div class="bc-sidebar">
                <p>I am sidebar text</p>
            </div> <!-- /bc-sidebar -->
            <p>I am the story section</p>



        </div> <!-- /col-md-12 /bc-story -->
    </div> <!-- /row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 bc-infographic">      
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3"> 
                <iframe src="infoAnimated/infoAnimated.html"></iframe>
            </div>
            <p>STEM education at a glance.</p>
        </div> <!-- /col-md-12 /bc-infographic -->
    </div> <!-- /row -->

</div> <!-- /container -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the content of the iframe?

Comment: It's just an animated infographic. Works totally fine.